# How do I get PiP to use my correct SSL root CA

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, pip, firewall

We're behind a firewall and for SSL connections they do a "man in the middle" attack and re-signs all certificates. I have fixed this on my machine by adding the custom root-certificate to my ca-setup as well as adding to my browsers. PiP does not seem to respect this. How can I either disable SSL checking in PiP or make it respect my list of CAs?

Here's the output:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyaml
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyaml/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyaml/ when looking for download links for pyaml
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pyaml
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyaml/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyaml/ when looking for download links for pyaml
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyaml
No distributions at all found for pyaml
Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377045/pip-cert-failed-but-curl-works

Comment: Never mind. Just saw the comment on the conf file. :)