# pip: cert failed, but curl works

Tags: python, curl, ssl, pip

We installed the our root cert on the client, and the https connection works for `curl`.

But if we try to use `pip`, it fails:

```
Could not fetch URL https://installserver:40443/pypi/simple/pep8/:
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
<urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed>
```

The cert is on the client. See:

```
(foo_fm_qti)foo_fm_qti@vis-work:~$ curl -v https://installserver:40443/pypi/simple/pep8/
* About to connect() to installserver port 40443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to installserver (127.0.0.1) port 40443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=DE; ST=Sachsen; L=Chemnitz; O=FOO-COM GmbH; OU=DV; CN=gray.foo-com.lan; emailAddress=info@foo-com.de
*    start date: 2013-09-09 10:47:50 GMT
*    expire date: 2019-05-24 10:47:50 GMT
*    subjectAltName: installserver matched
*    issuer: C=DE; ST=Sachsen; L=Chemnitz; O=FOO-COM GmbH; CN=FOO-COM Root CA; emailAddress=info@foo-com.de
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /pypi/simple/pep8/ HTTP/1.1
```

Version: pip 1.4.1

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unfortunately pip does not use the system certs, but curl does.

I found a solution:

```
pip --cert /etc/ssl/certs/FOO_Root_CA.pem install pep8
```

This is not nice (curl and other libraries find the cert without adding a parameter) but works.

If you don't want to use the command line argument, you can set the cert in ~/.pip/pip.conf:

```
[global]
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/Foo_Root_CA.pem
```

Comment: +1 the --cert argument did not work for me but the config file solution did (OS X, anaconda installation)

Comment: You can use `pip config set global.cert /path/to/cert` to have pip add this to the configuration file. On Linux you can point it to the system CA trust and pip will use the same certs as curl. On Debian (and derivatives) this is _/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt_

Answer (score 22):

My solution is downloading `cacert.pem` from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
and add the path for `cacert.pem` to `~/.pip/pip.conf` as guettli suggested

```
[global]
cert = /path/to/cacert.pem
```

Comment: I put this in /etc/pip.conf (the certificate was /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem) and it works for all users now

Answer (score 5):

For me, none of the config-file workarounds worked. I'm using **pip 1.5.4** on **Ubuntu 14.04**

The command posted by @arjenve didn't work on my system either. I get: `/usr/bin/python: No module named _vendor.requests`

**UPDATE**

An even better solution than my first workaround is installing the certificate on the system first (for me on ubuntu this would be)

```
sudo cp ~/my_cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

The previous automatically updates the bundle file (checking at the bottom of `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` you should now see the same certificate as in `my_cert.crt`)

Now export that path into `PIP_CERT` and add it to your `.bashrc`:

```
echo export PIP_CERT=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt >> ~/.bashrc
```

---

**OLDER WORKAROUND**

My workaround was to create a bundle file from `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and my corporate's crt (just concatenated both files). And then export a variable (put that on my `.bashrc`) like this:

```
export PIP_CERT=/my/path/to/the/bundle.crt
```

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
export PIP_CERT=`python -m pip._vendor.requests.certs`

pip install pep8
```

PIP always validates the certificate of HTTPS connections (and all pypi packages redirect to HTTPS).

The algorithm for determining the CA file is based on 3 steps:

1. Look in a list of default locations for different linux distributions
   (*in my case this file turned out to be out of date, as I am building on a very old linux distribution*)
2. If available, override the value found in (1) from a value in the pip.conf file, the environment or the command-line (in that order),
3. If both (1) and (2) did not result in a value, use a bundled file

*Note that pip does not use the default SSL directories and files (from ssl.get_default_verify_paths()). But only supports a bundled CA file.*

PIP does support a command-line action to list the bundled file from step 3 and that is what I use for this answer.

Comment: Why is the `pip install pep8` line needed?

Comment: That's just an example, I took it from the other answer

Comment: Oh, sorry it was late on Friday. Time for weekend :-)