# pip without SSL certificate checking?

Tags: python, ssl, pip

is there an older version of pip that doesn't check SSL certificates?

my corporate proxy replaces the cert from pypi with a company one which causes pip to abort the install.

I can download the packages manually and use pip on the local .tar.gz files but that is just a pain particularly with complex dependencies.

Comment: Using following approach may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19398611/2419207

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.2.1 works great for me as I'm always behind a corporate proxy.

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.2.1
```

I'm not sure of your situation, but I also had to install it on a shared VM so I built and installed it to my user directory (~/.local/)

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install --user
```

Update your path (~/.bashrc)

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Then install packages (fabric example)

```
pip install fabric --user
```