# python pip installation error 'cannot fetch base index URL'

Tags: python, powershell, pip, pypi

fairly new user but have basic understanding of command line/python. when attempting to install pip through windows 8 powershell get the following error message:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\xxxx\pip\pip.log
```

other instances of similar question seem to suggest something to do with proxy and then some more detailed linux instructions. i am unfamiliar with 'proxy' though if it's relevant i have a VPN extension in chrome. could somebody please suggest in simple, beginner language why i'm getting this error message/what the workaround and command prompt line would be?

appreciate it

contents of error log:

---

```
 get-pip.py run on 11/18/14 03:27:33
    Downloading/unpacking pip
      Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
      Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip
      Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
      Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pip
      Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
      URLs to search for versions for pip:
      * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
      Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
      Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip
      Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
    Cleaning up...
      Removing temporary dir c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_xxxx...
    No distributions at all found for pip
    Exception information:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmpb1cvmx\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmpb1cvmx\pip.zip\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
      File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmpb1cvmx\pip.zip\pip\req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
        url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
      File "c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmpb1cvmx\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
        raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
    DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pip
```

Comment: Check your internet connection. Can you open https://pypi.python.org/simple/ in your browser? Add links to the similar questions you found but don't understand.

Comment: thanks yes i can - it appears to be a list of links

Comment: What's the content of C:\Users\xxxx\pip\pip.log?

Comment: added to initial question (sorry if formatting is poor)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bundled SSL certificates seem to be out of date.
Check that you are following the [latest installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) and update your openssl installation.

Or try the solution outlined in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874741/2898712.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. have followed instructions + checked openSSL and both seem fine.

solutions in link assume pip is already installed. the error seems comparable yet i can't work out how to implement solution. eg:

'i found a solution'

pip --cert /etc/ssl/certs/FOO_Root_CA.pem install pep8

how can i modify this syntax assuming i do not have pip installed. my current cmd is simply:

python get-pip.py

Comment: Manually download pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.tar.gz#md5=6969b8a8adc4c7f7c5eb1707118f0686, extract and install with `python setup.py install`.