# python pip installation error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install pip using cygwin in windows 8 with a 32 bit OS. I have already installed python in cygwin (my python version is Python 2.7.10). For the installation of pip I downloaded d get-pip.py. from the following link:https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#python-and-os-compatibility.

Unfortunately I tried to install using the python get-pip.py command in cygwin but I got the following  error.

> Collecting pip
>     Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem  confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

I am working under the domain network so is it network issue or can you suggest any idea for installing pip?

Comment: Possible solution, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32831368/5781248

Answer (score 0):

If you have already python installed and added `python27/Scripts` folder to your system `PATH`, then install pip through easy_install.

Open a terminal and type:

```
easy_install pip
```

It should install pip to your python scripts folder and then you can use pip!

Comment: Actually i installed python 2.7.10 through cygwin , so can you please tell how can i go to further steps for installation of pip